# Create instance of a UIView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, instance, viewcontroller

I am designing an iOS app with 10 main UIViewControllers in it. Each representing a different section of the app. Its basically for a company and shows info about the company.

One of the things I am doing on bottom section of the app (in all the different view controllers) is displaying a UIView which contains a map. This map shows a certain location.

Now it works, but the problem I have is that I have 10 copies of the same code and 10 copies of the same UIView.

Is there anyway I could make a small view controller with one class attached to it that would handle the map and then just create an instance of the view controller in all my 10 view controllers in my app?

I hope my question makes sense. Basically I want to know how I can go about reusing ONE UIView in all 10 of my ViewControllers. So I can just call it or something and it appears.

**Update - this is basically what I am trying to achieve**

[image]

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View controllers can contain other view controllers. You can either use a container view in a storyboard or setup the relationship programmatically (see: [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)).

The storyboard container view is easiest, but the programmatic solution isn't too bad.

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
   // NOTE: You could also add it to any subview of self.view.
   [self.view addSubview:content.view];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (CGRect)frameForContentController
{
    return CGRectMake(…);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    …
    MyMapViewController *mapViewController = …;
    [self displayContentController:mapViewController];
    …
}

- (void)dismissContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

---

Final Note: Have each parent view create its own instance of the map view controller. Resist the temptation to reuse an instance of the map view controller between parents.

---

**Update to address questions**

> So lets say I had 2 of the same view controllers open at once and they both were displaying the same imported viewcontroller then it wouldn't work right?

You can't do this. An instance of a view controller can only have 1 parent view controller. Create separate instances for each use.

> So if I create different instances, I can reuse the same view lets say 5 times in one view?

Yes, if you create different instances, you can put as many as you need on a view.

Let me be clear, an instance is a distinct memory location created using a constructor.

```
MyMapViewController *mapViewController1 = [[MyMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMapViewController" bundle:nil];
MyMapViewController *mapViewController2 = [[MyMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

or

```
MyMapViewController *mapViewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
MyMapViewController *mapViewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
```

---

Updated to demonstrate dismissing a container view controller.

---

Here is a method for a child view controller, so it can use to dismiss itself.

```
- (void)dismissFromParentViewController
{
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff. Really helpful. Just one question though, this only works one at a time right? So you can't create more than one instance of a ViewController at once. Is that right? So lets say I had 2 of the same view controllers open at once and they both were displaying the same imported viewcontroller then it wouldn't work right?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff, as long as one `view` has only one `superview`, you need to create different instances or you can move the current instance to your visible container as `subview`.

Comment: Interesting. So if I create different instances, I can reuse the same view lets say 5 times in one view? And by different instance, am I right in saying that you simply mean creating another new pointer to the view controller like: ```MyMapViewController *mapViewController = …;  and then   MyMapViewController *mapViewController_2 = …; ```

Comment: @Supertecnoboff I updated my answer to clarify instance.

Comment: Honestly, I keep looking back to this answer from time to time when working on my projects. You have saved me A LOT of work. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Just one question, when I want to dismiss the controller, I use the ```removeFromSuperview``` method. Is that it? Do I need to do anything elso to ensure I don't use up too much memory?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff I added a `-dismissContentController:` example.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Thanks for the example. But how can this be executed from within the view controller thats being presented. I read online, that you can use NSNotifications to achieve this?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff It's easy for a child view controller to dismiss itself: no notifications needed. I posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below method:

- Create "map controller" super class with inherit to UIViewController and define your need common method and variables.
- Inherit your 10 child class into "map controller" super class. And connect common IBOutlets and IBActions to super class.
- You can access common methods and variable to super class from child class(10 view controller child class).

Please refer below code

```
@interface mapController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *mapControllerVariables;
}
-(IBAction)mapControllerActions:(id)sender;

@end
@interface yourChileView : mapController
{

}
@end
```